# Unity register / resolve Interface per Module

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, unity-container, prism

Our `Prism` Application uses a global `IRegionManager` and scoped `IRegionManager` for the `SubModules`. When I initialize my Module `SubModuleA` I create a new scoped RegionManager `RegionManagerA`. I want to register this Scoped RegionManager as `IRegionManager` but **ONLY** when resolved inside this Module.

For Example a `Search` View/ViewModel is shared via 4 `SubModules` and gets `IRegionManager` injected. When this shared `SearchView` is loaded inside `SubModuleA` then unity should inject `RegionManagerA` and so on...

I know this will be a lot easier with ninject, but time schedule is that `ninject` will not be implemented within the next few sprints ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not that familiar with Unity, so I can't give you the exact solution, but I  can give you the general pattern to solve this with though. The pattern to use here is the proxy pattern. You should create a proxy for `IRegionManager` that can forward the call to the region manager that should be used.

Example:

```
public class SelectorRegionManagerProxy : IRegionManager
{
    private readonly Func<IRegionManager> selector;
    public SelectorRegionManagerProxy(Func<IRegionManager> selector) {
        this.selector = selector;
    }

    // IRegionManager method(s) here.
    void IRegionManager.AnnoyEmployees() {
        this.selector.Invoke().AnnoyEmployees();
    }
}
```

This proxy will request the real `IRegionManager` when its methods are called and it forwards the call to the real instance.

This proxy can be registered instead of the real region manager implementations and since it has no state, it can be registered as singleton. During construction you can pass in a delegate that knows how to delegate to the real instance. For instance:

```
container.RegisterType<IRegionManager>(new SelectorRegionManagerProxy(() => 
    RunningInScopeOfSubModuleA()
        ? container.Resolve<RegionManagerA>()
        : container.Resolve<GlobalRegionManager>()));
```

Only the implementation of the `RunningInScopeOfSubModuleA()` check is something I can't help you with.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I think some logic is mossing. Registrations can be done in Bottsrapper/MainShell AND the SubModules, so the logic has to be: -Possibility to register mutiple instances to the same interface with conditions - Resolve instance based on this condition.

Answer (score 0):

Dependency overrides are often overlooked and could be used here. You have each module register its own region manager using a Named Registration.

Within each module you then specify that particular override to ensure the correct region manager is passed into the viewmodel:

```
//ModuleA
container.RegisterType<IRegionManager, RegionManagerA>("RegionManagerA")

//ModuleB
container.RegisterType<IRegionManager, RegionManagerB>("RegionManagerB")

//Some other point in Module B
//Resolve the specific RegionManager for Module B
DependencyOverride rm = new DependencyOverride(typeof(IRegionManager)
                         ,container.Resolve<IRegionManager>("RegionManagerB")); 

//and pass that as a dependency when the SearchViewModel is resolved
SearchViewModel vm = container.Resolve<SearchViewModel>(rm);
```

Comment: I would advise against using `DependencyOverride`s, just as I would advise against using child containers to override dependencies. This is error prone as can be seen [here](https://unity.codeplex.com/discussions/611770). If the `SearchViewModel` (or one of its child dependencies that depends on `IRegionManager`) is a singleton, your application will break silently.

Comment: This will work of course but then you need to be aware that there actually IS a different RegionManager with a name. My intendation is that I say within THIS Module I want to resolve a different RegionManager. So some kind of magic :D